# Respond on the same interface + netplan

Tags: routing, netplan

I'm unable to send response packets via the "right" interface when switching from `ip route` to `netplan`.

**The setup**:
server - two interfaces
`eth1`, vlan 101, 10.0.1.2/24, default route, 10.0.1.1 gate
`eth2`, vlan 102, 10.0.2.2/24

client
`eth0` vlan 102, 10.0.2.3/24, default route, 10.0.2.1 gate

There is a router (pfsense) in the middle that allows traffic between vlans.

**Repro steps**
When connecting from the client to the server using `10.0.2.2` everything works as expected.
When connecting from the client to the server using `10.0.1.2` The connection stays open for 30s and then communication stops. I believe that return packets from the server are sent using `eth2` interface as this route is a "better" match.

I found this suse article https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016626 that works for my case as long as I do this the `ip route` way.
eg:

```
ip route add 10.0.1.0/16 dev eth1 src 10.0.1.2 table T101
ip route add default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1 src 10.0.1.2 table T101
ip rule add from 10.0.1.2 table T101 prio 1

ip route add 10.0.2.0/16 dev eth2 src 10.0.2.2 table T102
ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth2 src 10.0.2.2 table T102
ip rule add from 10.0.2.2 table T102 prio 1
```

**Problem**
But I can't get similar result using netplan.

**my netplan attempt**:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
  vlans:
    vlan101:
      id: 101
      link: eth0
      addresses: [10.0.1.2/24]
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.0.1.2
        table: 101
        priority: 1
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.1.1
        scope: link
        from: 10.0.1.2
        table: 101
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.1.1
    vlan102:
      id: 102
      link: eth0
      addresses: [10.0.2.2/24]
      macaddress: dc:a6:32:c7:09:15
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.0.2.2
        table: 102
        priority: 1
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.2.1
        scope: link
        from: 10.0.2.2
        table: 102
  version: 2
```

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: I forgot to mention. The closest example I found was https://github.com/canonical/netplan/blob/main/examples/source_routing.yaml but that is still missing something, aka doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
  vlans:
    vlan101: # primary vlan with the gatewau
      id: 101
      link: eth0
      addresses: [10.0.1.2/24] # maybe good idea to add dns server 'nameservers'
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.0.1.2
        table: 101
        priority: 1
      routes:
      - to: 10.0.1.0/16
        from: 10.0.1.2
        table: 101
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.1.1
        scope: global
        from: 10.0.1.2
        table: 101
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.1.1
        from: 10.0.1.2
    vlan102: # you can have as many of those as you'd like
      id: 102
      link: eth0
      addresses: [10.0.2.2/24]
      macaddress: dc:a6:32:c7:09:15
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.0.2.2
        table: 102
        priority: 1
      routes:
      - to: 10.0.2.0/16
        from: 10.0.2.2
        table: 102
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.2.1
        scope: global
        from: 10.0.2.2
        table: 102
  version: 2
```